# How to pass the values of a file in a shell variable so that the variable can be used in a url for multiple values

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file `mwwtesrepos.xml` with values as

```
$cat mwwtesrepos.xml
test1
test2
test3
```

And I want to pass the values of the file *mwwtesrepos.xml*, one by one, in the `Base_Url`.

I have tried the following, but it's not working:

```
value=$(cat mwwtesrepos.xml)
echo $value

Base_Url="https://stash-url/rest/api/1.0/projects/MWWTES/repos/$value/permissions/groups?permission=1000"
```

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
while read -r value
do
    Base_Url="https://stash-url/rest/api/1.0/projects/MWWTES/repos/$value/permissions/groups?permission=1000"
    echo $Base_Url
done < mwwtesrepos.xml
```

`cat` is sometimes useful in a script, but more often it is misused.

Comment: This is working but only for the last value of the file mwwtesrepos.xml.

Comment: This is taking only "test3" which is the last value of the file mwwtesrepos.xml

Comment: This works for me.  Each iteration takes one value from the file and uses it in the URL.  What do you get from the `echo`?  Are you sure all three values are in the file the the format you how?

Comment: Yes, its working fine now. I was missing something in my script. Thanks!